# slicing numpy array to get nth column

Tags: python, numpy

Having the example array below, how do you slice by column to get the following (e.g. 3rd column) `[0, 0, ..., 1338, 1312, 1502, 0, ...]`
Looking for the most efficient way, thanks!

```
>>> r
array([[[   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0, 1338],
        [   0,    0, 1312],
        [   0,    0, 1502],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0, 1400],
        [   0,    0, 1277],
        [   0,    0, 1280],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0]]], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating

Comment: @BiRico link is not available anymore!

Comment: @arilwan https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a generic ndarray of any dimensions, one way would be -

```
arr[...,n]
```

To get a flattened version, use `.ravel()` method -

```
arr[...,n].ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [317]: arr
Out[317]: 
array([[[[2, 1, 2],
         [0, 2, 3],
         [1, 0, 1]],

        [[0, 2, 0],
         [3, 1, 2],
         [3, 3, 1]]],


       [[[2, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 3],
         [3, 3, 1]],

        [[2, 0, 1],
         [2, 3, 0],
         [3, 3, 2]]]])

In [318]: arr[...,2].ravel()
Out[318]: array([2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2])
```

Answer (score 3):

Numpy supports the "semicolon notation" like matlab. 
In your case you should be able to take the third column by doing:
`x = r[:,:,2]` 
 and then 
`a = numpy.concatenate([x[0],x[1],x[2]])`

Comment: You can use `x.flatten()` instead of `numpy.concatenate([x[0],x[1],x[2]])`.